# Storing and Retrieving Images using C++ Boost or STL and Mysql

Tags: c++, boost, stl

I am trying to persist images to my MySQL. Do anyone knows how to perform this using either Boost or STL? any useful links or snippets will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Where does Boost come into things? Boost has no libraries for DB connectivity....

Comment: Store the image as BLOB and when loaded to memory use Boost, well if available library - the librabry to process the image object.

Answer (score 0):

Though not part of boost you can use the SOCI database library, look at the documentation section on BLOBs.

http://soci.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Boost's generic image library will help you read and write images to disc, but cant encode to/decode from memory buffers. It also has methods to allow raw pointer access to image data. It would certainly help you pull the files into memory, and make the raw memory available for exporting. But you will have to find another way to connect them to the DB, or view them.